# JOIN on 3 tables with Propel ORM

Tags: php, orm, propel

One of my client is going to release a new product, the developer who was doing the coding left the project (with completing 85%).

A custom SQL query needs to be executed using Propel ORM. The query is as follows:

```php
$sql = "SELECT
    `domain`.*,
    `domain_registrar`.`name` AS `registrar_name`,
    `domain_account`.`id` AS `account_id`,
    `domain_account`.`username` AS `account_username`,
    DATEDIFF(`domain`.`expire_date`, NOW()) AS `days_to_expiration`

FROM
    `domain`
    LEFT JOIN `domain_account` ON `domain_account`.`id`=`domain`.`domain_account_id`
    LEFT JOIN `domain_registrar` ON `domain_registrar`.`id`=`domain_account`.`domain_registrar_id`

ORDER BY
    `days_to_expiration`,
    `domain_registrar`.`name`,
    `domain_account`.`username`,
    `domain`.`domain`";
```

I have very basic knowledge of propel ORM, so I thought any of the experts can help me to solve it.
The db scheme is like below:

```
<table name="domains" phpName="Domains">
    <column name="id" type="INTEGER" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
    <column name="account_id" type="INTEGER" required="true" />
    <column name="domain" type="VARCHAR" size="255" required="true" />
    <column name="expiration" type="DATE" />
    <foreign-key foreignTable="domain_accounts" phpName="DomainAccounts" refPhpName="Domains">
      <reference local="account_id" foreign="id" />
    </foreign-key>
  </table>
  <table name="domain_accounts" phpName="DomainAccounts">
    <column name="id" type="INTEGER" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
    <column name="registrar_id" type="INTEGER" required="true" />
    <column name="username" type="VARCHAR" size="255" required="true" />
    <column name="password" type="VARCHAR" size="255" required="true" />
    <foreign-key foreignTable="domain_registrars" phpName="DomainRegistrars" refPhpName="DomainAccounts">
      <reference local="registrar_id" foreign="id" />
    </foreign-key>
  </table>
  <table name="domain_registrars" phpName="DomainRegistrars">
    <column name="id" type="INTEGER" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
    <column name="value" type="VARCHAR" size="255" required="true" />
  </table>
```

Comment: What version of Propel is this? Propel 1.5 introduced `Query` classes to augment the `Peer` classes, which gives you a different syntax. (If you use `@Jan` in your reply I get a notification)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Propel 1.5 it would become something like this (untested, from the top of my head):

```
DomainsQuery::create()
    ->joinWith( 'Domains.DomainAccounts' )
    ->joinWith( 'Domains.DomainRegistrars' )
    ->withColumn( 'DATEDIFF(`domain`.`expire_date`, NOW())', 'DaysToExpiration' );
```